# Sets and data structures in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, set

Google Sheets's script editor seems to be a variant of JavaScript, but I can't figure out how to use it to handle Sets, dictionaries, etc. I already know how to use JS Arrays, **but Arrays are not sufficient for my task**.

Declaring a Set through the normal way (i.e. `var categoryOptions = new Set(String);` gives me a 'Set is not defined' error.

Using `var categoryOptions = {};` does not allow me to use any built-in Set functions, such as `add`. Instead, I get: "TypeError: Cannot find function add in object [object Object]."

Any pro tips?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google Apps Script runs on [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino). Rhino is fairly behind the times, it's about ECMAScript 5.1 level. Don't expect to have any ES6 features such as sets or arrow functions.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/issues/159) about Set in Rhino's GitHub repo. But even if it's implemented, it's not a given that Google would deploy the new version of Rhino on their servers.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Is there any official reference (e.g., documentation) I can cite that says Rhino is what Google uses for GAS?

Comment: I don't think there is one. Searching for "rhino" in the [GAS issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B%20rhino) brings up a few reports citing errors with "com.google.apps.maestro.rhino.WrappedException". There is also this [unofficial summary of the situation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764074#comment38). Plus personal experience: every time I ran into a bug in GAS implementation of JS, I was able to find that bug in Rhino tracker.

Comment: Looking for Rhino and AppEngine also gets some details, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658831/will-google-appengine-support-javascript/2658838

Comment: Yes, but Google App Engine is an entirely different product from Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 3):

Some news from the AppScript runtime overview https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

Historically, Apps Script has been powered by Mozilla's Rhino JavaScript interpreter. While Rhino provided a convenient way for Apps Script to execute developer scripts, it also tied Apps Script to a specific JavaScript version (ES5). Apps Script developers can't use more modern JavaScript syntax and features in scripts using the Rhino runtime.

> To address this concern, **Apps Script is now supported by the [V8 runtime](https://v8.dev/)** that powers Chrome and Node.js. You can migrate existing scripts to V8 in order to take advantage of the modern JavaScript syntax and features.

Answer (score 3):

try using this code:

```
function test() {
let search_from_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2];
let search_data = ['c', 'a', 'd', 'z', 2, 3, 4, 5];
let search_set = new Set();
for ( let i = 0 ; i < search_from_data.length ; i++ )
    search_set.add(search_from_data[i]);
for ( let i = 0 ; i < search_data.length ; i++)
    Logger.log([search_data[i], "Is present?", search_set.has(search_data[i])]);
}
```

[This Image is the output for the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMDEZ.png)

> Apps Script is now supported by the V8 runtime that powers Chrome and Node.js. You can migrate existing scripts to V8 in order to take advantage of the modern JavaScript syntax and features. Reference:
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It is not about how to use `Set`. It is about `Set` not being supported by Google Apps Script.

Comment: It is supported now, try running the above code in a GAS console.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Apps Script is running on Rhino 1.7r3. Here's a write up on what is supported and what is not.

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/rhinoversion

Answer (score 1):

While Appscript itself is still way behind the ES times, using the Google maintained Clasp tool does let you now develop app script using Typescript in an officially supported way which will let you use `Set()` and all the other language features.

https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md

Note the big constraint here, once you shift to using Typescript you can no longer develop/debug your code in the app script script editor as you will be looking at the transpiled code.

Similarly there are also non-google projects to transpile to appscript code from ESx using webpack and babel.

eg https://github.com/labnol/apps-script-starter

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ES6 shim for Apps Script, so you can use things like Set and Map. The IDE of course won't support arrow functions or anything else that might break the 5.1 syntax.

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/es6shim